# Error when uploading picture

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to upload a picture through my admin page and keep getting Errno 13. I have no clue what is going wrong, any help would be great.

Here are the lines of code from my model,

```
image_object = models.ImageField(db_column='IMAGE_OBJECT',upload_to = "/media/", blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
```

setting,

```
ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '/media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

and httpd.conf files

```
Alias /media /path_to_media_folder/media/


<Directory /path_to_media_folder/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Django application does not have write access to the media directory, you need to set up [permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions) so that it does.

Comment: I've already used chmod 777 on my media folder. Still not working.

Comment: @R.N.G make sure you have 777 on the parent folder of the media dir as well.

Comment: @R.N.G could you post the full exception traceback?

Comment: Turns out that by removing the "Require all granted" fixed my problem